# Javascript Rotating Image Width needs to conform to window

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, width

SITE: http://www.elsolstudio.com/demo/avoya/index.html

Right now, when I size down the window, it's making the white background on the lower right mess up. I need the javascript rotating image to conform to whatever size the window is, and not make the width of the window larger.

Comment: I like your site! the spinning body is a really cool effect.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the rotating element inside an `overflow:hidden` container.

Comment: that made the element completely invisible

Comment: give the container a height and width.

Comment: #holder {
 background-color:#63aef7;
    height: 600px;
 width:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
    margin-left:-1000px;
 margin-top:-140px;
 margin-right:auto;
    position: absolute;


}